# Did Moses beseech God twice?

Tags: exodus, moses, deuteronomy

> Exodus 32:11-13
>  (A) And Moses besought the LORD his God, and said,
>   LORD, why doth thy wrath wax hot against thy people, which thou hast
>   brought forth out of the land of Egypt with great power, and with a
>   mighty hand?
>
> Wherefore should the Egyptians speak, and say, For mischief did he
>   bring them out, to slay them in the mountains, and to consume them
>   from the face of the earth? Turn from thy fierce wrath, and repent of
>   this evil against thy people.
>
> (B) Remember Abraham, Isaac, and Israel, thy servants, to whom thou
>   swarest by thine own self, and saidst unto them, I will multiply your
>   seed as the stars of heaven, and all this land that I have spoken of
>   will I give unto your seed, and they shall inherit it for ever.

From the verses above, it's the story when the first forty days and forty nights Moses up at the mountain to receive the first stone tablet.

Later, I found in Deuteronomy, the story when Moses was up at the mountain for forty days and forty nights for the second time. He said :

> Deuteronomy 9:26-27
>  (C) I prayed therefore unto the LORD, and
>   said, O Lord GOD, destroy not thy people and thine inheritance, which
>   thou hast redeemed through thy greatness, which thou hast brought
>   forth out of Egypt with a mighty hand.
>
> (D) Remember thy servants, Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob; look not unto
>   the stubbornness of this people, nor to their wickedness, nor to their
>   sin:

The sentence in point A (the first time at the mountain) almost the same with point C (the second time at the mountain) and the sentence in point B (the first time at the mountain) almost the same with point D (the second time at the mountain).

My question :

1. Did Moses beseech God twice ?

> Exodus 32:14
>  So the LORD changed His mind about the harm which He
>   said He would do to His people.

later on Moses said :

> Exodus 32:27
>  And he said unto them, Thus saith the LORD God of
>   Israel, Put every man his sword by his side, and go in and out from
>   gate to gate throughout the camp, and slay every man his brother,
>   and every man his companion, and every man his neighbour.

and

> Exodus 32:35
>  And the LORD plagued the people, because they made
>   the calf, which Aaron made.

2. What does it mean of the sentence in Exodus 32:14, while He still kill (indirectly) 3,000 Israel people and then He plagued the rest who live ?

It's not mentioned in Exodus when Moses up at the mountain 40 days and 40 nights for the second time that he beseech to God, but in Deuteronomy (point C and D) it seems Moses besought God (again) when he is up at the mountain for the second time as read in point-C and point-D.

I have my own answer, but my answer doesn't agree from what I've read in Exodus because I have to change the verse by put the *"beseech to God"* read in point A and B should have happened when Moses for the second time up at the mountain as read in Deuteronomy (so, the "beseeching God" happen only once) .... and consequently, *"God change His mind"* in Exodus 32:14 is also not happen when Moses up at the mountain in the first 40 days 40 nights but the second time one.

That's why I have the question here.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question would be, yes. Deuteronomy 10:10 confirms that Moses 'besought' God after he went back up the mountain having broken the tables. Exodus 32:11-13 has Moses promptly 'beseeching' God after the declaration of Exodus 32:7-10, which declaration occurred before Moses descended the mountain the first time, and so also his corresponding request(vss. 11-13). Moses is found in several other places interceding in a similar way(Numbers 11:2,12:13-14,21:7-8, Deuteronomy 3:23-26).

Comment: User40520, so what does it mean of the sentence in Exodus 32:14, while He still kill (indirectly) 3,000 Israel people and then He plagued the rest who live which caused Moses beseech to Him for the second time ?

Comment: It seems the first(Exodus 32:14) prevented the immediate response from God(cmp 1 Chr. 21:11-12), in comparison to Deuteronomy 9:26, where Moses suspected it were not ubiquitous.